# iOS mapkit - How can I show text on hover of a pin

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, swift2, mapkit

I am using iOS 9 with Swift 2.

I have been unable to find a way of displaying text on hover of a pin that exists on a map using mapkit.

I would like to do this without having to have a callout, which forces the user to click on the pin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a "hover" per say like with a web app. There is either tap (selected) or no tap (unselected), but terminology aside, you're going to want to use an MKAnnotationView. Specifically I'd replace it with a UILabel using this method:

```
func viewForAnnotation(_ annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
```

That will let you set the view to be whatever you want, so create the UILabel view, then set it to be your annotation view there

Answer (score 0):

Set MKAnnotarion.title property, then you can see the value on TAP. As mentioned above comment, there is no Hover concept in iOS